# Wmode transparent and symbols issue with foreign keyboard

Tags: actionscript-3, input, keyboard, transparent, wmode

I have the known issue with wmode transparent and input textfield in my page.
I know that the question is often asked but I have a special situation with that case.

I need to embed my swf with wmode=transparent but in my swf I have an input textfield and the bug with "@" or "." symbols exists.

I have a french keyboard and I decided to overcome this problem with a string replacement with the FirefoxWmodeFix class from Manmaru (see the link below).

http://www.manmaru.fr/mlab/?p=95

It works for my keyboard but I need that "trick" with EN/DE/IT keyboard.
Could anyone help me with the right combination of keys on different keyboard and different OS system to display "@" and "." symbols.

I don't have any foreign Windows system to get the key code for each combination.

Or if anyone has another solution, I will be pleased to hear that one.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: So you want to know which keys to press on a DE or EN keyboard to get @ and . ?

Answer (score 0):

wmode transparent is a known source of countless bugs -- specifically affecting proper text rendering. If you solve (hack your way around) this one, you *will* find more. :(